# how to bind listView ItemsSource to base type but pass in specific type

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom User Control that has a ListView. 
I also have a simple object hierarchy where 'Group' 'Questions' and so on all inherit from BaseEntity.

I am trying to create a user control that can bind to any BaseEntity type and show its Name and Id(base type properties). this way I can re-use it throughout the application for whatever ObservableCollection basic details I want to display in the control

it works when I bind an ObservableCollection of BaseEntity but not a specific type. unless I change the dependency properties to be that specific type - but that defeats the whole point.
How can I cast down to the base type on binding in xaml?

so I could bind with collections of:

```
ObservableCollection<Group>//inherits from BaseEntity
or 
ObservableCollection<OtherType>//inherits from BaseEntity
or 
ObservableCollection<BaseEntity> //its a BaseEntity
```

ideally, something like {Binding Path=(BaseEntity)OwnedGroups} - but it's not being that straight forward

==================the Control.xaml.cs==============

```
public partial class InOrOutControl : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<BaseEntity> EntitiesOwned
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<BaseEntity>)GetValue(EntitiesOwnedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EntitiesOwnedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EntitiesOwnedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(EntitiesOwned), typeof(ObservableCollection<BaseEntity>), typeof(InOrOutControl), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<BaseEntity>(), SetOwnedItemsSource));

    private static void SetOwnedItemsSource(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InOrOutControl controll = d as InOrOutControl;
        if (controll != null)
        {
            controll.OutItemsLV.ItemsSource = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<BaseEntity>;
        }
    }

    public InOrOutControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

=================Control xaml=================

```
<UserControl x:Class="HonorsProject.View.CustomControlls.InOrOutControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HonorsProject.View.CustomControlls"
         xmlns:appCore="clr-namespace:HonorsProject.Model.Core;assembly=HonorsProject.Model"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Name="InOrOutCtrl"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <ListView Name="OutItemsLV"
              ItemsSource="{Binding EntitiesOwned, ElementName=InOrOutCtrl}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Height="100"
              Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

==============the control in the Page===============

```
<uc:InOrOutControl x:Name="InOrOutControl"
                            EntitiesOwned="{Binding Path=OwnedGroups,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

===============Base Type========

```
 public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

=============Specific type========

```
public class Group : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public int SomeSpecificProperty {get;set;}

    public Group()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast for a Binding. `Text="{Binding Name}"` works by reflection, i.e. with any object that has a public Text property.

Comment: The problem I'm having is getting the item source to pick up the collection I'm trying to bind to it - The Dependency properties aren't picking up that the ObservableColleciton<Group> is a BaseEntity. I was hoping i could just be like: here's a list of Groups/something else and it would take that becasue it can see that Groups are BaseEntities allowing me to bind the BaseEntity property of Name to the list view item. but it doesnt.

Comment: Perhaps because you have `ItemsSource="{Binding EntitiesAvailable, ElementName=InOrOutCtrl}"` but the property is `EntitiesOwned`. It's unclear what you are actually doing. Please make sure your question shows a minimal reprodicible example.

Comment: copy paste slip while making the question - should be better now

Comment: You should declare the property as `IEnumerable<BaseEntity>`. Then you can assign e.g. a `ObservableCollection<OtherType>()`. Also note that setting `new ObservableCollection<BaseEntity>()` as default value in PropertyMetadata is a programming error. All instances of your control would use the same collection object by default.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to have solved it! - So from the little bit of homework I've done since your post. LIstViews ItemsSource is an IEnumerable type so if the dependency property is a more specific type it'll try to cast up and cause issues. keeping its base type avoids this?